# How to create REST API in magento after configuring REST Roles , OAuth Consumers and Users with that role?

Tags: magento-1.9, php, api, rest-api, zend-framework

I am not that much aware of API. I have created `REST Roles` and `OAuth Consumers`. After that i have created New user and assign that role to that user.

I know that I need to create one `php` or `xml` file.

But I don't know how to start and where to start.

I need to create API for following cases for third-party app:

**1... Product Master**

**1) Fetching the product data from E-comm site.**

-> First time the product information from the E-commerce site will be downloaded using the service in 3rd Party app database.

**2) Product management.**
-> Product will be directly downloaded and cloned into the database of 3rd Party app CMS. Manually 3rd Party app will map the products with the categories.

**3) Service call identification**
-> Service call identification to be done with the timestamp. Every time when 3rd Party app requests the product data will pass the timestamp sent by the E-commerce site from previous call. Using this E-commerce site will identify which products were shared in last call and will only pass the updates post last timestamp.

**2... Order Request**

**1) Order processing** 
-> 3rd Party app will complete the order processing along with the payment on app. Service call will be made to E-commerce site indicating that respective order has been placed for x products.

**2) Order log**
-> 3rd Party app will store the log of each order for future reference.

**3... Order Tracking**

**1) Order tracking**
-> Once the order is processed at E-comm site (received from the 3rd party app) E-commerce site should consume the service provided by the 3rd party app to share the tracing information along with mail body.

**2) Sharing tracking information with buyer**
-> 3rd party app will be sharing the information received using the service on email as a notification to the user.

**3) Manual tracking**
-> 3rd party app user may choose to check the delivery status real-time using the app.

**Please help or give some useful hint asap.**